# Find no of discontinuity of the function $f(x)=\max\{[x^2];x \in[0,2]\}$

Tags: calculus

Here $[y]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to y.

My effort: $f(x)=0$ when $0\le x<1$

```
            =1 when x=1 ; so x is a point of discontinuity

            =2 when $x^2>2; so x is a point of discontinuity


            =3 when $x^2>3; so x is a point of discontinuity

            =4 when x=2 ;so x is a point of discontinuity
```

Hence no of discontinuity is 4. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = \begin{cases} 0, &x\in [0,1) \\ 1, & x\in [1,\sqrt 2) \\ 2,& x\in [\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) \\ 3, & x\in [\sqrt 3, 2) \\ 4, & x=2 \end{cases} $$ From here it is easy to deduce that in $[0,\sqrt 2)$, $x$ will be greater than $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$, and in $[\sqrt 2, 2]$, $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor $ is greater. Hence, $$f(x) =\begin {cases} x, & x\in [0,\sqrt 2) \\ \lfloor x^2 \rfloor, & x\in [\sqrt 2,2] \end{cases} $$ Before, $\sqrt 2$, we have no discontinuities, but there are discontinuities at $x=\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, 2$ arising from the floor function, giving a total of $\mathbf 3$ discontinuities.